# How to use Chrome

Tags: android, web-applications

i have very simple ask from u and i hope u r not be sad to answer it because of it so easy level.

im beginner in android programming but have enough ability to build what i want to in web app so please guide me how could i build android app that include all my web page and order to android system to using chrome to open it easily and smoothly without any choose option menu to how open webpage (because maybe installed another browsers on the device) in the android studio. so the result should to be like this: user see the app icon, tap on it, automatically open chrome and leads to web app. i know there is the WebView component and read many articles about it, i want using exactly chrome (or what ever browser i exactly need to) so if i miss understood about that or anything dont be shy and please share ur truly useful comment with me. i dont know how could i say thanks to every one of you because your attention to my problem so without any complements thanks u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
String urlString="http://mysuperwebsite";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
try {
    context.startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    // Chrome browser presumably not installed so allow user to choose instead
    intent.setPackage(null);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

This will open up the Chrome Browser with the url set in the urlString

Comment: *unless user has no chrome installed. That way it will ask of which browser to use instead.